# Visual studio debug errors

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, visual-studio-2019

When ever I try to debug my project I get these error messages
I have tried resetting my ios simulator and reinstalling. Any help would be much appreciated!

````
error 1:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(3,3): Error: actool exited with code 1 (LifeHacks)

error 2
/Users/christianbadenhausen/Projects/LifeHacks/LifeHacks/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone 11-13.3/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets: Error: Distill failed for unknown reasons. (LifeHacks) actool

error 3
/Users/christianbadenhausen/Projects/LifeHacks/LifeHacks/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone 11-13.3/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets: Error: 2020-02-04 19:29:21.593 ibtoold[6651:494977] DEBUG: Added to environment: {

    TMPDIR = "/var/folders/cx/j1ybrk4s0p7_4pps5bh1q_400000gn/T/AF653337-2853-4350-AC13-B15859597D25";

}

2020-02-04 19:29:23.318 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[6673:496229] Unable to get image dimensions for file:///Users/christianbadenhausen/Projects/LifeHacks/LifeHacks/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone%2011-13.3/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon1024.png

2020-02-04 19:29:23.323 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[6673:496229] Unable to get image dimensions for file:///Users/christianbadenhausen/Projects/LifeHacks/LifeHacks/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone%2011-13.3/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon120.png

2020-02-04 19:29:23.324 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[6673:496229] Unable to get image dimensions for file:///Users/christianbadenhausen/Projects/LifeHacks/LifeHacks/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone%2011-13.3/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon120.png```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFot8.jpg
````

Comment: please do NOT post errors as images

Comment: @Jason I just updated the question!

Comment: kill VS, delete all bin/obj folders in project, restart VS, rebuild

Comment: @Jason by kill you mean close out of the VS tab right

Comment: exit the application

Comment: @Jason what is the location of these folders

Comment: @Jason This didn't work

Comment: @Jason I moved the bin and obj folders to the trash and then deleted them, no luck.

Comment: Make sure that you had filled all size of icon in iOS project-<Assets . And you could create a new blank project to check if the issue still exists.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT what do you mean by filled all size off icon, also I have tried making new ios projects and it hasn't worked

Comment: What is the version of your IDE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out all I had too do was update my mac to the latest version

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people .